# Is there anyway to have Trigger.io work with Firebase's Facebook SimpleLogin?

Tags: trigger.io, firebase-security

We're currently using Firebase's Email SimpleLogin API with our Trigger.io app and would like to add Facebook login as well.  In addition to checking for session, we're storing user specific information provided by the firebase user object.  Hence, we would like to keep using the Firebase SimpleLogin API for our Facebook login, instead of the native Facebook module provided by Trigger.io (https://trigger.io/modules/facebook/current/docs/index.html).

While trying to add the Firebase Facebook SimpleLogin, the Trigger.io app seems to bomb out with the 'redirect loop' error (in the web version) and the generic Trigger.io error in the simulator.

We are not sure if we need to follow the "OAuth with modal view", as we're not certain what to put in for the "url" and "pattern" (https://trigger.io/docs/current/recipes/integrations/modal.html).

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

-Tony